# Pillow issue: grayscale image unexpectedly rendered in color

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

When I load a grayscale JPEG image using `Pillow.Image.open()` and plot it using `pyplot.image()`, the result has unexpected garish colors.  I suspect that I'm doing something wrong.  Any advice will be appreciated.  Here's my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from PIL import Image

image_array= Image.open('01.Ned and Clara.jpg')
pyplot.imshow(image_array)
pyplot.show()
```

Phillip

Comment: And the image appears grey in other viewers? What do you mean 'garish'? Can you reproduce the problem with other images?

Comment: I'm kind of suspicious of the image itself. To Karl's point, can you reproduce it with other pictures / formats ?

Comment: Both Windows Paint and Paint Shop Pro display this image as a grayscale image.  It should be a grayscale image because the original source was a photo made with a black-and-white camera.

Comment: I've uploaded the original grayscale image and a screen shot of what gets displayed by the above code.  The URL is as follows: http://phillipmfeldman.org/Python/images/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the colormap to force grayscale

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.cm as cm

image_array= Image.open('01.Ned and Clara.jpg')
pyplot.imshow(image_array,cmap = cm.Greys_r)
pyplot.show()
```